# Ошибка при установке tkinter через pip

Tags: python, tkinter, pip

Помогите,устанавливаю `tkinter` через `pip3` выдаёт ошибку:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f9cde24fca0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -3] Временный сбой в разрешении имен')': /simple/tk/
```

Пробовал множество способов в написании имени библиотеки(`tkinter`, `Tkinter`, `tk`, `Tk`) не помогло.
И да система у меня `Linux Ubuntu`

Comment: 1 - у вас какая-то сетевая ошибка. 2 - tkinter не ставится через pip

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте написать в терминал вот эту команду:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install python3-tk
```

После этого импортируйте модуль в программу